# Driver failed programming external connectivity in Angular db

Tags: html, angular, typescript, docker-compose

Driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint angular4_db_1 bind for port is already allocated.
error: for database cannot start service database.
userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:5432 failed: port is already allocated

Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

During composing my angular program I got this error .
Help me to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Open the Docker Container. And just stop the running programe. Then run the required Program you will be able to use the command

**docker-compose up -d**

Will easily solve the Error.

Answer (score 0):

To open angular dev server on another port you can use

```
ng serve --host localhost --port 4201 --open
```